# Asking people to leave the group

Tags: problem-players, group-dynamics

I'm just going to get straight to the point 
I recently just finished DMing a short campaign that hadn't gone as well as I hoped but people still seemed to enjoy themselves and want to play again!

As much as I do want to DM again I am slightly hesitant to play with certain players again due to them causing many issues that plagued the last campaign.

Such as Not paying attention, constantly talking over me when im trying to relay important information, and disrupting the game multiple times with dumb forced jokes like it was a Monty python sketch that forgot to be funny.

I have tried talking to them multiple times but they just don't listen to me.
I have tried to be patient but Im fed up, I don't want to play with these people anymore but I don't know how to tell them this without them just continue to push me to let them join regardless or them feeling like Im being a killjoy.

How do I tell them I don't want them in the group without things getting to rocky.

Comment: Do you want to play with some of the players again, or none of them?

Comment: @greysage
There are some people in the group that I do want to play with again, there's just a few people I'd rather not play with within the group because of the problems they caused

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, by the way! Strange that no one has welcomed you here, yet.